# opencart 1.5.6.4 check email availability when register

Tags: opencart

I want to check the email in the opencart registration page from the database using json (or ajax?) so there will be a note in the registration form if it's available or not.

Any help please?
Thanks

Ok, so this is what I've done so far

signup.tpl

```
<tr>
      <td><span class="required">*</span> <?php echo $entry_email; ?><br />
            <div id="email_availability_result"></div>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td><input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" />
        <?php if ($error_email) { ?>
        <span class="error"><?php echo $error_email; ?></span>
        <?php } ?></td>
    </tr>
```

**signup.tpl**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#email').keyup(function(){
            var email = $('#email').val();
            if(email.length > 2) {
                $('#email_availability_result').html('Loading..');
                var post_string = 'email='+email;
                $.ajax({

                    dataType: 'json',
                    type : 'POST',
                    data : post_string,

                    url: 'index.php?route=account/signup/emailCheck',

                    success: function(json) {
                        $('.success, .warning, .attention, information, .error').remove();

                        if (json['success']) {
                            $('#email_availability_result').html('<span class="success">' + json['success'] + '</span>');
                        }

                        if (json['warning']) {
                            $('#email_availability_result').html('<span class="success">' + json['warning'] + '</span>');
                        }   
                    }

                });
            }else{
                $('#email_availability_result').html('');
            }
        });
    });
```

**signup.php (controller)**

```
public function emailCheck() {

    $this->load->model('account/signup');

    $json = array();

    if(isset($this->request->post['email'])){

        $email = $this->request->post['email'];

        $result = $this->model_account_signup->getEmailBySignUp($email);

        $json['success'] = "Email name available";

        $json['warning'] = "Email already taken";

    }

    $this->response->setOutput(json_encode($json));
}
```

**signup.php (model)**

```
public function getEmailBySignUp($email) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT count(*) as total FROM `" . DB_PREFIX . "user` WHERE email = '" . $this->db->escape($email) . "'");
    return $query->row['total'];
}
```

It's not working.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is already in the open cart,but it will working on page reload.You can check it on

`Catalog/accounts/register.php function name getTotalCustomersByEmail()`

You can call this model function through ajax,and can show instant message for the email address checking.

Comment: Thanks Tanmoy, but I'm just a newbie. I can see the code you've mentioned but I don't know how to do it. Could you please write it here how to do it?

Comment: Just write a js  with an event  for the email field, there you write an ajax , in the controller by that function we can do this.If you want see how to call ajax, then go to view/template/checkout/checkout.tpl ,you find lots of ajax calling there.

Comment: I've just updated it but it is still not working. What is wrong with it?

Comment: There is lots of syntax error in the signup tpl js code, i have corrected it. Now check it once.